# How to change the colors of a specific Visual Studio Element

Tags: visual-studio-2010, colors, fonts, settings

pretty simple one but I'm trying to find out which item in the Font & Colors list these are.  I'm trying to change the light/grey white @Razor colors.

[image: code sc]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2010 goes to Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors > at "Show settings for" dorpdown select "Text Editor" > at Display items box find Razor Code and than change the background color.

Good luck.